# Djikstra Algorithm to avoid or not to avoid an obstacle vertex

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

Okay, first forgive my english, second I want to ask you this question that comes into my mind all of sudden and trying to figure it out which I find hard to do it,

Im quite understand how Djikstra works, and I know how to make a program with C++ of that Djikstra, the thing is, I want to add an obstacle, which is a vertex, that this vertex may be qualified as below :

> 1. this vertex is one of vertices of shortest path to a final vertex that Djikstra will choose of course in his step,
> 2. BUT, this vertex in this case must be avoid for some reason such as a traffic jam, which is not pretty hard, just tell Djikstra to not to choose the vertex which I programmed like : deleting the vertex from my graph, so Djikstra will aim for another shortest path of course,
> 3. in case finding another shortest path, I find that my program wont update the path to the final vertex, which I realize that the "obstacle vertex" must be included to the path, because there's no way to the final vertex without taking the "obstacle vertex",
> 4. I try to make a conditional statement on it, if the path wont updated then, do not delete the vertex from the graph,
> 5. I got the final result,

But, I dont know how to solve this program into a bigger case, for like 5-6 obstacle vertex, lets say, I delete all the 6 vertex, and end up with no result, which vertex should I redelete?

Comment: IIUC you have a given graph, start and end vertices, and a set $U$ of undesirable vertices, and you want to find a path from start to end which, as much as possible, avoids vertices in $U$? If you can't avoid $U$ entirely, there may be different subsets of $U$ which work and you need to decide how to compare them. Do you just want to minimise the number of undesirable vertices? Or maybe assign them different costs?

Comment: I'd try to figure your reply, I hope I dont misunderstood, because my lackness of english, yes in my case there're like 6 undesirable vertices, which then I have to avoid any of them, but if I avoid all of them, I will end up with no result, so the case is how do I find which undesirable vertex to add to my shortest path? I have try to figure it out, but I end up with a pain in my head,maybe do you have some clue to make it simple?

Comment: and ya, i want to minimise the number of undesirable vertices.

Comment: Normally Dijkstra has a priority queue ordered by distance from the start node. Instead order it by the pair (number of undesirable vertices, distance from start node). The first entry should be incremented whenever you follow an edge to an undesirable vertex.

Comment: Note also that the answer may not be unique; eg if the graph is a square and we want to get from top left to bottom right, and the other two vertices are undesirable, we can use either one.

Comment: I got a clue already, I dont know if it is true or not. I'll try to make a program that ignores the undesirable vertex, and when it comes to a result which is a shortest path, I will try to find whether it has an undesirable vertex in it or not with queue ordered by distance from the start node, if it does (lets say that undesirable vertex X), then I will find the node that adjacent with X and trying to find another shortest path to the node that also adjacent with that X, if it exist, then I get a new shortest path, if it not, then I must not avoid that X. How do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71334/discussion-between-yagami-and-stewbasic).

Comment: @Yagami The easiest way to do this is to increase the cost of visiting the undesirable vertex high enough (e.g., if there is a traffic jam, it is still a valid road, only that the time is much higher, so you adjust accordingly, depending on the situation, in some cases it still might be the best route). What stewbasic suggests is a way of representing the cost were having even one "undesirable vertex" if infinitely worse that whatever else you can find in the rest of the graph (while this might not be a good model for traffic jams, it is quite useful in other problems).